# Use of custom fields in CQWP

Tags: content-query-web-part

We have a custom field in a custom page type to denote the published date. A cqwp is used to retrieve a list of pages from a pages list and we need to display this published date.

Normally this would not be a problem, but this published date pulls through as $Resources:ContentTypeNews, which does not work in common view fields, assuming the fact that this is an embedded resource? I don't have the code for this, so I'm working purely on assumptions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pulls through'...?

Comment: Assuming you want a publishing date to be displayed, why would this be embedded? Each column(field) can be displayed through the CQWP, even the default columns like Created, Author(Created By), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457%28v=office.14%29.aspx) describes how to display custom properties in the CQWP?